# import/export xml for dbunit

Tags: xml, dataset, export, dbunit

Ｈow can we easily import/export database data which dbunit could take in the following format?

```
<dataset>
   <tablea cola="" colb="" />
   <tableb colc="" cold="" />
</dataset>
```

I'd like to find a way to export the existing data from database for my unit test.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you read the documentation at dbunit.org?

Comment: Ｉ do it manually or use a postgresql client. Just wondering if there is any better way. @MarkRobinson

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Blue, this will let you export your data in the format you wanted.

```
public class DatabaseExportSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // database connection
        Class driverClass = Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        Connection jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:hsqldb:sample", "sa", "");
        IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection);

        // partial database export
        QueryDataSet partialDataSet = new QueryDataSet(connection);
        partialDataSet.addTable("FOO", "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL='VALUE'");
        partialDataSet.addTable("BAR");
        FlatXmlDataSet.write(partialDataSet, new FileOutputStream("partial.xml"));

        // full database export
        IDataSet fullDataSet = connection.createDataSet();
        FlatXmlDataSet.write(fullDataSet, new FileOutputStream("full.xml"));

        // dependent tables database export: export table X and all tables that
        // have a PK which is a FK on X, in the right order for insertion
        String[] depTableNames = 
          TablesDependencyHelper.getAllDependentTables( connection, "X" );
        IDataSet depDataSet = connection.createDataSet( depTableNames );
        FlatXmlDataSet.write(depDataSet, new FileOutputStream("dependents.xml"));
    }
}
```

Comment: @blue123, that snippet is from the FAQ, which has other information you may find useful:  http://www.dbunit.org/faq.html#extract

Comment: This copy-pasted snippet contained the same error as in the FAQ

Comment: URL above is broken. Use this one: http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#extract

Answer (score 7):

Exporting is already answered.
To complete the answer, this is how you can **import** your dataset into database.
`connection` is of type `IDatabaseConnection`.
The previous answer (of exporting) by Mark Robinson, contains the code of how to create a database connection.

```
FlatXmlDataSet dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSet(new FlatXmlProducer(new InputSource(new FileInputStream("dataset.xml"))));
DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(connection, dataSet);
```

Comment: The first line can be simply `FlatXmlDataSet dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSet(new File("dataset.xml"), true);` or `FlatXmlDataSet dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new File("dataset.xml"));`